# База данных: количество полей

Tags: mysql

Как влияет количество полей на скорость и работу базы данных?

Например, хочу для таблицы пользователей создать 50 полей. Запрос и обновление данных этой таблицы на каждой странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, количество полей влияет на производительность. Но то, насколько существенно это влияние, зависит от разных факторов - числа записей в таблице, сложности ваших запросов. Хотя, насколько я знаю, это влияние будет не особо существенно (впрочем, привести каких-то числовых показателей не смогу).

Главное тут, на мой взгляд, другое - то, что если вы хотите  создать таблицу с пятьюдесятью столбцами, то вам стоит всерьез задуматься о том, что вы делаете что-то не так. Скорее всего, имеет смысл вынести большую часть этих столбцов в другие таблицы, связав их с оригинальной внешними ключами